# How to resolve standradError In ROR-4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Can any body find out the solution for this error ?I am following this  [Link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and tring to make one app.First i typed command 
"rails generate paperclip user avatar".when i ran command rake db:migrate,it gave this error.

Error:

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "avatar_fil
e_name" varchar(255)c:/Site/attachment1/db/migrate/20141220045244_add_attachment
_avatar_to_users.rb:4:in `block in up'
c:/Site/attachment1/db/migrate/20141220045244_add_attachment_avatar_to_users.rb:
3:in `up'
C:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

my 20141220045244_add_attachment_avatar_to_users.rb file contains

```
class AddAttachmentAvatarToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.attachment :avatar
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :users, :avatar
  end
end
```

Please help to resolve this error.

Comment: `no such table: users`

Comment: Does your app have a Users model/table?

Comment: Loading the rake db:schema:load corrected the issue.

Comment: check: 1> if there exists a table user 2> are you using correct database in database.yml

Comment: @subhra : You should have user model to add avatar for user. please check your model or post your schema file.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is there is no 'users' table.
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users